# Guake does not show end of text line

Tags: 12.04, guake

Working on Ubuntu 12.04, Guake 0.4.3.

Faced with inappropriate behavior with end of text lines (left side of screen) that are displayed on Guake.

See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot with issue]

Also I navigate to /etc to find any settings to configure:

```
alexander@alexander-U36SD:/etc$ sudo grep -rl "guake" ./
./xdg/autostart/guake.desktop
alexander@alexander-U36SD:/etc$ cat ./xdg/autostart/guake.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Guake Terminal
Name[pt]=Guake Terminal
Name[pt_BR]=Guake Terminal
Comment=Use the command line in a Quake-like terminal
Comment[pt]=Utilizar a linha de comando em um terminal estilo Quake
Comment[pt_BR]=Utilizar a linha de comando em um terminal estilo Quake
TryExec=guake
Exec=guake
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/guake/guake.png
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

But, not sure is it right place to configure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have just run into this bug: [Dual monitor + side panel causes problem](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/179).

Excerpt:

> But when using two monitors plus a side panel, the guake panel starts
>   just after the panel, as it should, but then goes on not until the end
>   of the first monitor, but a little more.
>
> --> Hard to explain, just look at the screenshot. You can see the end of the first screen from the maximised Firefox window.
>
> That means, you have the guake terminal basically on the first screen,
>   but the last character or so plus the scroll bar is on the second
>   one...

[image: Image attached to the above bug report]

I think you should report it at [GitHub's Guake repository](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/new).

Source: http://guake.org/

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was helpful for me. I found how to fix.
Additionally, file name that described in https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/179 non-exist. Instead of /usr/lib/guake/guake.py need to edit /usr/bin/guake:790

Comment: I'm glad you've found it helpful! Please do not hesitate to post your solution and accept that if it solves this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found solving for my question. Need to edit /usr/bin/guake file at line 790

```
---
self.window.resize(window_rect.width, window_rect.height)

+++
self.window.resize(window_rect.width-24, window_rect.height)
```

Here we can change size of content to display.

That's my result:

[image]